# Is there a limit to how many billing plans can I create?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

we are developing a system with a possibility for the user to set a custom price for their recurring payment. This means that each user should have a unique billing agreement with our system. Will paypal allow this? This could result in having (potentially) thousands of different billing plans.

If subscriptions is not the option - what could be used as an alternative to this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Actually it is a programming question since it concerns the API. We have an identical question and PayPal docs are of no help. They are just saying how to setup a recurring payment but nothing about an intended usage

Comment: Kristis do you have an update on this one?

Comment: Kristis - Did you make any headway with this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was told by Paypal support that there is no limit on how many billing plans you have created.